# print list as 4 column and x rows grid using angular and bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. I want to print this list as a bootstrap grid (class="col-x") using angularjs.

I want to create 4 column and 3 rows grid from this list.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just assigning them a .col-size-3 class will create 4 columns.

Comment: I did this: <div ng-repeat="val in value" class="row">
   <div class=".col-size-3">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="space"></div>
    {{val}}
   </div>
  </div> and it not working

Comment: Try putting the ng-repeat with che class .col-xs-3, for example, inside the row:

    <div class="row">
        <li ng-repeat="val in value" class="col-xs-3">
            ...
        </li>
    </div>

Also you could try to make a working example using http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Also see this similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592298/structure-issues-using-ng-repeat-with-bootstrap-and-angularjs